# Is there any limitation for UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

is there any limitation for **UPDATE** statement, I have to update records in table which contains large amount of dataset, is there any possibility for error occurs during update. I have to run script on crown job.

Comment: Yes, there is always possibility that something goes wrong(data integrity, incorrect value, resource pressure,...).

Comment: no i am not providing any parameter to query, i want to just reset flag in table, and table contains very large dataset.

Comment: I guess you are asking if you need to do error handling in your script? Yes, you do unless you don't care if it fails. Even if your script doesn't need parameters it can fail for several reasons, lad listed some, there are more, but since you just asked if there are *any*, one should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but this depends on your storage engine and some options:

- The [`--safe-updates`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates) option prohibits you from updating rows unless "you specify a key constraint in the `WHERE` clause or provide a `LIMIT` clause (or both)"
- InnoDB (the default storage engine) is transactional, and locks all affected rows during the operation, which will limit concurrent access. You can use this to your advantage if an error occurs to roll back the change and recover from it later.
- MyISAM (widely used older engine) is faster, but less robust, and you risk losing changes if an error occurs during a large update.

Otherwise, this sort of operation is not that unusual so you should find if you're using a proper storage engine that you'll have no difficulty besides slow performance during the update.